# About growth rate of function

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Suppose the function $ d(T)→\infty $as $ T→∞ $, what is the appropriate growth rate of $ d(T) $ in order that

$ d(T)^{2d(T)-1}/T^c→0 $ with $c$ being a constant?

Thanks very much for your kind help.

Comment: $$\limsup_{T\to\infty}\left(\frac{\log\log T}{\log T}d(T)\right)\lt\frac{c}2$$

Comment: @Did Thanks very much. Would you please give me some hints on how to get the $\log \log T / \log T$ stuff?